# React router not redirecting on server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a high order component that checks if a user is authenticated and if not will redirect to a different url.

Its an isomorphic app and this works client-side but if I turn JS off, the server doesn't redirect.

```
if (!this.props.authenticated) {
    this.context.router.push('/');
}
```

I can hit this statement on the server and `this.context.router` is returning but nothing happens.

Full Component:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default function (ComposedComponent) {
    class Authentication extends Component {
        static contextTypes = {
            router: React.PropTypes.object
        }

        static propTypes = {
            authenticated: PropTypes.bool
        }

        componentWillMount() {
            if (!this.props.authenticated) {
                this.context.router.push('/');
            }
        }

        componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
            if (!nextProps.authenticated) {
                this.context.router.push('/');
            }
        }

        render() {
            return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />;
        }
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return { authenticated: state.auth.authenticated };
    }

    return connect(mapStateToProps)(Authentication);
}
```

and this component is reached via the routes file:

```
export default (
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Welcome} />
        <Route path='/feature' component={requireAuth(Feature)} />
        <Route path='/signin' component={Signin} />
        <Route path='/signout' component={Signout} />
        <Route path='/signup' component={Signup} />
    </Route>
);
```

This is the server render code:

```
import { RouterContext, match } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import React from 'react';
import reactCookie from 'react-cookie';

import configureStore from '../../shared/store';
import routes from '../../shared/routes';
import assets from '../../public/assets.json';

import { AUTH_USER } from '../../shared/actions/types';

export default function (req, res) {
    match({ routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
        if (error) return res.status(500).send(error.message);
        if (redirectLocation) return res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
        if (!renderProps) return res.status(404).send('Page not found');

        const store = configureStore();

        // use cookies to retrieve token
        const unplug = reactCookie.plugToRequest(req, res); // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
        const token = reactCookie.load('token');

        // if we have a token, consider the user to be signed in
        if (token) {
            // we need to update application state
            store.dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER });
        }

        const content = renderToString(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
            </Provider>
        );

        const initialState = JSON.stringify(store.getState());

        return res.render('index', { content, assets, initialState });
    });
}
```

Comment: You've turned JS "off". How do you expect it to work?

Comment: Its an isomorphic app using node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share your server rendering code? It probably needs to look something like https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ServerRendering.md , where you're checking the `redirectLocation` flag. That `redirectLocation` can be returned by using an `onEnter` hook instead of a wrapper component. The `onEnter` hook is documented [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback).

Update from comment below: Ok so your server code is correctly checking `redirectLocation`, but the routing code needs to be using an `onEnter` hook to set that `redirectLocation` properly. Like so:

Ok, so you're correctly honoring `redirectLocation` in the server code, but `redirectLocation` is only populated using an onEnter hook, like so:

```
const userIsInATeam = (nextState, replace) => {
  if ( !isAuth ) {
    replace('/')
  }
}

<Route path="/users/:userId/teams" onEnter={userIsInATeam} />
```

I think `nextState` should have the `auth` prop you're looking for in it to check auth.

Comment: Thanks - it now looks as though its redirecting back to the root, however now getting two new errors

`Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'children' supplied to 'Route'.
    in Router`

and

`Warning: [react-router] Location "/" did not match any routes`

Comment: Ignore that - needed to add the `const routes = createRoutes(store);` into the client side as well.

Marking this as the correct answer - thanks